# my pip3 installation on osx is very confused, how can i fix it?

Tags: macos, pip, python-3.6

i have too many installations of python3 in my mac and i can't go on.

`which python3` gives me:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

but

```
pip3 -V
```

gives me:

```
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

now when i install something with pip it goes on the wrong directory (this happen after i upgraded pip3 i guess)

the problem is that in the past i installed some pip3 packages inside this folder: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`  and everytime i run python3 i just can importe those ones.

how should i fix this confusion? i guess i need to remove this version of pip3 and reinstall the version compatible with python 3.6 to install packages in the good directory (the old one)
but how to do that?

thanks

Comment: The first thing to do is decide whether you want to use Python 2.7 as delivered by Apple with `macOS`, Python 3.6 as delivered by Apple with `macOS` or Python 3.7 as installed by **homebrew**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running in virtual environments. One option is to load Anaconda and from Anaconda you can easily set up you virtual environments. Anaconda uses conda instead of pip and you won't have the confusion of multiple pips. The command you use to set up a virtual environment is `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda`. There are documents showing you how to use [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html) and how to install and use [Virtual Environments](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/). This may sound daunting but Anaconda makes this easy. I have virtual environments for python 2.7.13, 3.65 and 3.7. Its simple to pick the one I want.